# react native missing readAsArrayBuffer

Tags: react-native, amazon-s3, blob, filereader

I'm trying to convert an uri image (retrieved with react-native-image-picker) to an array buffer to upload the file to s3 (since s3 does not support form-data for put requests I can't use it)

this is my code

```
    let fetched = await fetch(pictureInfo.uri)
    console.log("Fetched uri:", fetched)
    let arrayBuffer = await fetched.arrayBuffer()
```

but running it I receive

> **Error: FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is not implemented**

How can I convert it to a buffer and upload to s3 without converting it to base64?

Answer (score 1):

Without going for the base64 method, you can upload the image file directly using the `react-native-fetch-blob` package.

Assuming that you have `aws-sdk` for `react-native`

```
// Add Config

AWS.config.update({
    region: // Your Region,
    accessKeyId: // Your Access key,
    secretAccessKey: // Your Secret Key,
    sessionToken: // Your Session Token,
});

// Initialize
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

// Get Signed Url
const signedUrl = await s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', {
    Bucket: // Your Bucket,
    Key: // Your Key,
    ContentType: // Content Type, example `image/jpg`,
});


const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const upload = await RNFetchBlob.fetch('PUT', signedUrl, {
    'Content-Type': // Content Type
}, RNFetchBlob.wrap(localPath)); // where local path would be your local image path ${image.uri}
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid generating base64 out of images, since pics are obtained throught camera roll (or directly from camera) and base64 can be quite heavy to generate. I'm looking for a method to upload directly the file from the uri

Comment: `ImagePicker` already provides with two options, either to access the `local file uri` or `base64` in `response.data`

Comment: In imagepicker you can set a parameter to avoid generating base64. Point is, when I use FormData, payload is sent as multipart, which is not supported by S3. The only way is to use base64?

Comment: To append the data into `FormData ` you either need a `blob` or `USVString`, and to generate a blob, you either need a new package `RNFetchBlob` or convert it using `fetch api` from `base64`.

Comment: React native has a polfill for FormData https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/c6b96c0df789717d53ec520ad28ba0ae00db6ec2/Libraries/Network/FormData.js#L25 and you can send images using their URIs, but this will generate a multipart request

Comment: If that is possible then you might be able to attach the file type objects as mentioned [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/announcing-the-amazon-s3-managed-uploader-in-the-aws-sdk-for-javascript/)

Comment: That could be an option (given it is compatible with react native), but I don't really want to pull into my project the whole s3 aws package for just an upload function

Comment: The rest depends upon you, which option you think is the easiest to implement.